# How to rotate coordinates (x,y) of an image at a specific angle

Tags: python, opencv

To best understand, please reproduce the code in a Jupyternotebook:

I have two files: img.jpg and img.txt. Img.jpg is the image and img.txt is the face landmarks....If you plot them both, it will look like this:

[image]

I rotated the image by 24.5 degree....but how to do I also rotate the coordinates?

[image]

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()


# In[130]:


landmarks = []
with open('img.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        landmarks.extend([float(number) for number in line.split()])
landmarks.pop(0) #Remove first line. 
#Store all points inside the variable. 
landmarkPoints = [] #Store the points in this
for j in range(int(len(landmarks))):
    if j%2 == 1:
        continue
    landmarkPoints.append([int(landmarks[j]),int(landmarks[j+1])])


# In[ ]:

def rotate_bound(image, angle):
# grab the dimensions of the image and then determine the
# center
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
(cX, cY) = (w // 2, h // 2)

# grab the rotation matrix (applying the negative of the
# angle to rotate clockwise), then grab the sine and cosine
# (i.e., the rotation components of the matrix)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])

# compute the new bounding dimensions of the image
nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))

# adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

# perform the actual rotation and return the image
return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH)) 



# In[131]:


imgcopy = img.copy()
for i in range(len(landmarkPoints)):
    cv2.circle(imgcopy, (landmarkPoints[i][0], landmarkPoints[i][1]), 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)
plt.imshow(imgcopy)
plt.show()
landmarkPoints


# In[146]:


print(img.shape)
print(rotatedImage.shape)


# In[153]:


face_angle = 24.5
rotatedImage = rotate_bound(img, -face_angle)
for i in range(len(landmarkPoints)):
    x,y = (landmarkPoints[i][0], landmarkPoints[i][1])
    cv2.circle(rotatedImage, (int(x),int(y)), 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)
plt.imshow(rotatedImage)
plt.show()
```

Please download img.jpg and img.txt for reproducing this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FhQUFvoKi3t7TrIepx2Es0mBGAfT755w/view?usp=sharing

I tried this function, but y-axis is wrong

```
def rotatePoint(angle, pt):
    a = np.radians(angle)
    cosa = np.cos(a)
    sina = np.sin(a)
    return pt[0]*cosa - pt[1]*sina, pt[0] * sina + pt[1] * cosa
```

Edit: The above function gives me this result:

[image]

Comment: why don't you simply rotate `imgcopy` instead of `img`?

Comment: I want to save the new coordinates in a new file. Rotating the imgcopy 
 image will not give me the new coordinates in text file.

Comment: I added rotate_bound function also

Comment: Okay...I got it.....The answer is to add the last row + last column value of the "M" in  rotate_bound to y axis.

Comment: @JohnBott If you found the answer yourself, it is encouraged to write an answer to your own question. This way in the future, people can find the answer too!

Comment: use function affineTransform on the points

Comment: if only perspectiveTransform function exists, just add a (0,0,1) row to your transformation

Answer (score 1):

Although it has been long time since the question was asked. But I have decided to answer it as it has no accepted answer yet, even if it is a well accepted question. I have added a lot of comments to make the implementation clear. So, the code is hopefully self-explanatory. But I am also describing the `ImageAugmentation`'s parameters for further clarification:

Here, `original_data_dir` is the directory to the parent folder, where all of the image's folders exists (yes it can read from multiple image folders). This parameter is **compulsory**.

`augmentation_data_dir` is the folder directory where you want to save the outputs. The program will automatically create all sub-folders inside of the output directory just like they appear in input directory. It is totally **optional**, it can generate the output directory by mimicking the input directory by appending the string `_augmentation` after the input folder name.

`keep_original` is another **optional** parameter. In many cases you may want to keep the original image with the augmented images in the output folder. If you want so, make it `True` (default).

`num_of_augmentations_per_image` is the total number of augmented images to be generated from each image. Although you wanted only rotation, but this program is designed to do other augmentations as well, change them, add or remove them as you need. I have also added a link to documentation where you will find other augmentations which can be introduced here in this code. It is defaulted to `3`, if you keep the original image, there will be `3 + 1 = 4` images will be generated in the output.

`discard_overflow_and_underflow` is for handling the case where due to spatial transformation, the augmented points along with the image underneath can go outside of image's resolution, you can optionally keep them. But it is discarded here by default. Again, it will also discard images having `width` or `height` values `<= 0`. Defaulted to `True`.

`put_landmarks` means if you want the landmarks to be shown in the output. Make it `True` or `False` as required. It is `False` by default.

Hope you like it!

```
import logging
import imgaug as ia
import imgaug.augmenters as iaa
from imgaug.augmentables import Keypoint
from imgaug.augmentables import KeypointsOnImage
import os
import cv2
import re

SEED = 31 # To reproduce the result

class ImageAugmentation:
    def __init__(self, original_data_dir, augmentation_data_dir = None, keep_original = True, num_of_augmentations_per_image = 3, discard_overflow_and_underflow = True, put_landmarks = False):
        self.original_data_dir = original_data_dir

        if augmentation_data_dir != None:
            self.augmentation_data_dir = augmentation_data_dir
        else:
            self.augmentation_data_dir = self.original_data_dir + '_augmentation'

        # Most of the time you will want to keep the original images along with the augmented images
        self.keep_original = keep_original

        # For example for self.num_of_augmentations_per_image = 3, from 1 image we will get 3 more images, totaling 4 images.
        self.num_of_augmentations_per_image = num_of_augmentations_per_image

        # if discard_overflow_and_underflow is True, the program will discard all augmentation where landmark (and image underneath) goes outside of image resolution
        self.discard_overflow_and_underflow = discard_overflow_and_underflow

        # Optionally put landmarks on output images
        self.put_landmarks = put_landmarks
        

    def get_base_annotations(self):
        """This method reads all the annotation files (.txt) and make a list
        of annotations to be used by other methods.
        """
        # base_annotations are the annotations which has come with the original images.
        base_annotations = []

        def get_info(content):
            """This utility function reads the content of a single annotation
            file and returns the count of total number of points and a list of coordinates
            of the points inside a dictionary. 
            
            As you have provided in your question, the annotation file looks like the following:

            106
            282.000000 292.000000
            270.000000 311.000000
            259.000000 330.000000
            .....
            .....

            Here, the first line is the number of points.
            The second and the following lines gives their coordinates.
            """

            # As all the lines newline separated, hence splitting them
            # accordingly first
            lines = content.split('\n')

            # The first line is the total count of the point, we can easily get it just by counting the points
            # so we are not taking this information.

            # From the second line to the end all lines are basically the coordinate values
            # of each point (in each line). So, going to each of the lines (from the second line)
            # and taking the coordinates as tuples.
            # We will end up with a list of tuples and which will be inserted to the dict "info"
            # under the key "point_coordinates"
            points = []
            for line in lines[1:]:
                # Now each of the line can be splitted into two numbers representing coordinates
                try:
                    # Keeping inside try block, as some of the lines might be accidentally contain
                    # a single number, or it can be the case that there might be some extra newlines
                    # where there is no number.
                    col, row = line.split(' ')
                    points.append((float(col), float(row)))
                except:
                    pass
            
            # Returns: List of tuples
            return points


        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(self.original_data_dir):
            for file in files:
                ext = os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower()
                # Looping through image files (instead of annotation files which are in '.txt' format) 
                # because image files can have very different extensions and we have to preserve them.
                # Whereas, all the annotation files are assumed to be in '.txt' format.
                # Annotation file's (.txt) directory will be generated from here.
                if ext not in ['.txt']: 
                    input_image_file_dir = os.path.join(subdir, file)
                    # As the image filenames and associated annotation text filenames are the same,
                    # so getting the common portion of them, it will be used to generate the annotation
                    # file's directory.
                    # Also assuming, there are no dots (.) in the input_annotation_file_dir except before the file extension.
                    image_annotation_base_dir = self.split_extension(input_image_file_dir)[0]
                    # Generating annotation file's directory
                    input_annotation_file_dir = image_annotation_base_dir + '.txt'

                    try:
                        with open(input_annotation_file_dir, 'r') as f:
                            content = f.read()
                            image_annotation_base_dir = os.path.splitext(input_annotation_file_dir)[0]
                            
                            if os.path.isfile(input_image_file_dir):
                                image = cv2.imread(input_image_file_dir)
                                # Taking image's shape is basically surving dual purposes.
                                # First of all, we will need the image's shape for sanity checking after augmentation
                                # Again, if any of the input image is corrupt this following line will through exception
                                # and we will be able to skip that corrput image.
                                image_shape = image.shape # height (y), width (x), channels (depth)

                                # Collecting the directories of original annotation files and their contents.
                                # The same folder structure will be used to save the augmented data.
                                # As the image filenames and associated annotation text filenames are the same, so 
                                base_annotations.append({'image_file_dir': input_image_file_dir,
                                                        'annotation_data': get_info(content = content),
                                                        'image_resolution': image_shape})
                    except:
                        logging.error(f"Unable to read the file: {input_annotation_file_dir}...SKIPPED")
                    

        return base_annotations        

    
    def get_augmentation(self, base_annotation, seed):
        image_file_dir = base_annotation['image_file_dir']
        image_resolution = base_annotation['image_resolution']
        list_of_coordinates = base_annotation['annotation_data']
        ia.seed(seed)

        # We have to provide the landmarks in specific format as imgaug requires
        landmarks = []
        for coordinate in list_of_coordinates:
            # coordinate[0] is along x axis (horizontal axis) and coordinate[1] is along y axis (vertical axis) and (left, top) corner is (0, 0)
            landmarks.append(Keypoint(x = coordinate[0], y = coordinate[1])) 
            
        landmarks_on_original_img = KeypointsOnImage(landmarks, shape = image_resolution)

        original_image = cv2.imread(image_file_dir)

        """
        Here the magic happens. If you only want rotation then remove other transformations from here.
        You can even add other various types of augmentation, see documentation here: 
            # Documentation for image augmentation with keypoints
            https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/examples_keypoints.html
            # Here you will find other possible transformations
            https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/examples_basics.html
        """
        seq = iaa.Sequential([
                iaa.Affine(
                    scale={"x": (0.8, 1.2), "y": (0.8, 1.2)}, # scale images to 80-120% of their size, individually per axis
                    translate_percent={"x": (-0.2, 0.2), "y": (-0.2, 0.2)}, # translate by -20 to +20 percent (per axis)
                    rotate=(-90, 90), # rotate by -90 to +90 degrees; for specific angle (say 30 degree) use rotate = (30)
                    shear=(-16, 16), # shear by -16 to +16 degrees
                )
            ], random_order=True) # Apply augmentations in random order

        augmented_image, _landmarks_on_augmented_img = seq(image = original_image, keypoints = landmarks_on_original_img)

        # Now for maintaining consistency, making the augmented landmarks to maintain same data structure like base_annotation
        # i.e, making it a list of tuples.
        landmarks_on_augmented_img = []
        for index in range(len(landmarks_on_original_img)):
            landmarks_on_augmented_img.append((_landmarks_on_augmented_img[index].x,
                                               _landmarks_on_augmented_img[index].y))

        return augmented_image, landmarks_on_augmented_img

 
    def split_extension(self, path):
        # Assuming there is no dots (.) except just before extension
        # Returns [directory_of_file_without_extension, extension]
        return os.path.splitext(path) 


    def sanity_check(self, landmarks_aug, image_resolution):
        # Returns false if the landmark is outside of image resolution.
        # Or, if the resolution is faulty.
        for index in range(len(landmarks_aug)):
            if landmarks_aug[index][0] < 0 or landmarks_aug[index][1] < 0:
                return False
            if landmarks_aug[index][0] >= image_resolution[1] or landmarks_aug[index][1] >= image_resolution[0]:
                return False
            if image_resolution[0] <= 0:
                return False
            if image_resolution[1] <= 0:
                return False
        return True


    def serialize(self, serialization_data, image):
        """This method to write the annotation file and the corresponding image.
        """
        # Now it is time to actually writing the image file and the annotation file!
        # We have to make sure the output folder exists
        # and "head" is the folder's directory here.
        image_file_dir = serialization_data['image_file_dir']
        annotation_file_dir = self.split_extension(image_file_dir)[0] + '.txt'
        point_coordinates = serialization_data['annotation_data'] # List of tuples
        total_points = len(point_coordinates)

        # Getting the corresponding output folder for current image
        head, tail = os.path.split(image_file_dir) 

        # Creating the folder if it doesn't exist
        if not os.path.isdir(head):
            os.makedirs(head)

        # Writing annotation file
        with open(annotation_file_dir, 'w') as f:
            s = ""
            s += str(total_points)
            s += '\n'
            for point in point_coordinates:
                s += "{:.6f}".format(point[0]) + ' ' + "{:6f}".format(point[1]) + '\n'

            f.write(s)

        if self.put_landmarks:
            # Optionally put landmarks in the output images.
            for index in range(total_points):
                cv2.circle(image, (int(point_coordinates[index][0]), int(point_coordinates[index][1])), 2, (255, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imwrite(image_file_dir, image)



    def augmentat_with_landmarks(self):
        base_annotations = self.get_base_annotations()
        
        for base_annotation in base_annotations:
            if self.keep_original == True:
                # As we are basically copying the same original data in new directory, changing the original image's directory with the new one with re.sub()
                base_data = {'image_file_dir': re.sub(self.original_data_dir, self.augmentation_data_dir, base_annotation['image_file_dir']), 
                                      'annotation_data': base_annotation['annotation_data']}
                self.serialize(serialization_data = base_data, image = cv2.imread(base_annotation['image_file_dir']))


            for index in range(self.num_of_augmentations_per_image):
                # Getting a new augmented image in each iteration from the same base image.
                # Seeding (SEED) for reproducing same result across all execution in the future.
                # Also seed must be different for each iteration, otherwise same looking augmentation will be generated.
                image_aug, landmarks_aug = self.get_augmentation(base_annotation, seed = SEED + index)
                
                # As for spatial transformations for some images, the landmarks can go outside of the image.
                # So, we have to discard those cases (optionally).
                if self.sanity_check(landmarks_aug, base_annotation['image_resolution']) or not self.discard_overflow_and_underflow:
                    # Getting the filename without extension to insert an index number in between to generate a new filename for augmented image
                    filepath_without_ext, ext = self.split_extension(base_annotation['image_file_dir'])
                    # As we are writing newly generated images to similar sub folders (just in different base directory)
                    # that is replacing original_data_dir with augmentation_data_dir.
                    # So, to do this we are using, re.sub(what_to_replace, with_which_to_replace, from_where_to_replace)
                    filepath_for_aug_img_without_ext = re.sub(self.original_data_dir, self.augmentation_data_dir, filepath_without_ext)
                    new_filepath_wo_ext = filepath_for_aug_img_without_ext + '_' + str(index)
                    augmentation_data = {
                        'image_file_dir': new_filepath_wo_ext + ext,
                        'annotation_data': landmarks_aug
                    }
                    self.serialize(serialization_data = augmentation_data, image = image_aug)


# Make put_landmarks = False if you do not want landmarks to be shown in output
# original_data_dir is the single parent folder directory inside of which all image folder(s) exist.
img_aug = ImageAugmentation(original_data_dir = 'parent/folder/directory/of/img/folder', put_landmarks = True) 
img_aug.augmentat_with_landmarks()
```

Following is a snapshot of sample output of the code:
[image: sample-output]

Please note that, I have used a package `imgaug`. I will suggest you to install the `0.4.0` version, as I have found it to be working. See the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62580797/in-colab-doing-image-data-augmentation-with-imgaug-is-not-working-as-intended) and it's accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you try things like that it's very important to choose the proper coordinate system. In your case you have to put the origin `(0,0)` point in the center of the image.

Once you apply the rotation to the coordinates with the origin point in the center, the face points will be properly aligned on the new image.