# How do I perform Data Augmentation for landmarks localization?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, data-augmentation

I'm building a neural network using Keras to perform landmarks localization on a grayscale images.

I saw that for classification task there is a Keras function to perform Data Augmentation. But for localization task I have not found a function to perform Data Augmentation since in the labeled data there are points to be changed.

Any idea to perform Data Augmentation for landmarks localization task?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some more information what your data looks like. Do you use images (RGB or grey) or pointclouds. Also I don't really know what you mean with point localization. Is it just object detection, so predicting the bounding box or something else?

Comment: I've update post with new information

Comment: Is it helpful?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68641675/6907424

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is anything you can use out of the box in keras.
But what you can always do is write your own data augmentation. The only real difference to data augmentation for e.g. classification is that you also have to keep track of your landmarks.

So if you do a flipping you have to also flip the coordinates of your landmarks. Same with rotation, if you rotate around some angle you also have to rotate the landmarks. If you do cropping you have to transform the landmark coordinates to the new cropped image, which is just a simple translation and removing the points which are not in the new image.

On how to do this you can have a look here
https://medium.com/the-artificial-impostor/custom-image-augmentation-with-keras-70595b01aeac

or just in general search for something like "custom image augmentation in keras".